# How to turn this ID-based objects into an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have data like this:

```
{
  "-L8BpxbS70KYrZMQUF0W": {
    "createdAt": "2018-03-22T16:33:57+08:00",
    "email": "ss@ss.ss",
    "name": "ss"
  },
  "-KYrZMQUF0WL8BpxbS70": {
     // etc.
   }
}
```

Which I want to turn into this:

```
[{
  id: '-L8BpxbS70KYrZMQUF0W
  createdAt: "2018-03-22T16:33:57+08:00",
  email: "ss@ss.ss",
  name: "ss"
}, {
  id: -KYrZMQUF0WL8BpxbS70"
  // etc.
}]
```

I'm started with this:

```
  Object.keys(idBasedObjects).forEach(key => {
    console.log(resp[key])
  })
```

But I get `undefined`.

What's best way of creating this array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get the keys and values using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), and [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) them to to the required form using [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals):

```js
const obj = {"-L8BpxbS70KYrZMQUF0W":{"createdAt":"2018-03-22T16:33:57+08:00","email":"ss@ss.ss","name":"ss"},"-KYrZMQUF0WL8BpxbS70":{}};

const result = Object.entries(obj).map(([id, props]) => ({
  id,
  ...props
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I gotta say. This is a very clean and elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Object.keys`, `Object.assign` and `map`

```
var output = Object.keys(obj).map( s => Object.assign( obj[s], {id : s} ))
```

**Demo**

```js
var obj = {
  "-L8BpxbS70KYrZMQUF0W": {
    "createdAt": "2018-03-22T16:33:57+08:00",
    "email": "ss@ss.ss",
    "name": "ss"
  },
  "-KYrZMQUF0WL8BpxbS70": {
    "createdAt": "2018-03-22T16:33:57+08:00",
    "email": "s2s@ss.ss",
    "name": "ss2"
  }
};

var output = Object.keys(obj).map(s => Object.assign(obj[s], {
  id: s
}));

console.log(output);
```